# When should I use StandardScaler and when MinMaxScaler?

Tags: neural-network, feature-selection, feature-scaling, classifier

I have a feature vector with One-Hot-Encoded features and with continous features.

How can I decide now, which data I shall scale with StandardScaler and which data scale with MinMaxScaler? I think I do not have to scale the one-hot-encoded anyway because they are already between 0 and 1.

(I use afterwards a MLPClassifier)

Comment: Rule of thumb: Use StandardScaler for normally distributed data, otherwise use MinMaxScaler.

Answer (score 13):

> StandardScaler and MinMaxScaler are more common when dealing with
> continuous numerical data.

One possible preprocessing approach for OneHotEncoding scaling is "soft-binarizing" the dummy variables by converting `softb(0) = 0.1, softb(1) = 0.9`. From my experience with feedforward Neural Networks this was found to be quite useful, so I expect it to be also benefitial for your MLPClassifier.

**StandardScaler** is useful for the features that follow a [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). This is clearly illustrated in the image below ([source](https://jovianlin.io/feature-scaling/)).

[image]

**MinMaxScaler** may be used when the upper and lower boundaries are well known from domain knowledge (e.g. pixel intensities that go from 0 to 255 in the RGB color range).

Answer (score 11):

In **"Python Machine Learning" by Raschka** the author provides some guidance on page 111 when to normalize (min-max scale) and when to standardize data:

> Although normalization via min-max scaling is a commonly used technique that is useful when we need values in a bounded interval, standardization can be more practical for many machine learning algorithms. The reason is that many linear models, such as the logistic regression and SVM, [...] initialize the weights to 0 or small random values close to 0. Using standardization, we center the feature columns at mean 0 with standard deviation 1 so that the feature columns take the form of a normal distribution, which makes it easier to learn the weights. Furthermore, standardization maintains useful information about outliers and makes the algorithm less sensitive to them in contrast to min-max scaling, which scales the data to a limited range of values.

Answer (score -2):

StandardSCalar changes the shape of data while keeping data into range of 0 and 1. It can eliminate the outliers(which sometimes provides some useful info).
NOTE: Do not remove all outliers until you do not have domain knowledge sbout them.

MinMaxScalar() do not changes the shape of data, while it also keeps the data into range of 0 and 1. It will do it for minimum number of features required.