# Compare two tends with big difference in absolute value

Tags: data-mining, data, visualization, data-analysis

I'm studying the Spotify streams trend for different nations in order to show the impact of the pandemic on music listeners.

So far i retrieved my data, and plotted it.

[image: Streams trend]

Obviously, since the various nations have different numbers in population, spotify users ecc... this graphic doesn't tell much.

So i decided to scale every curve dividing its values by its peak. 
 So for example, the US has a maximum value of 3.50 million streams, i normalized that curve with that value and i did the same for all the other states (with their maximum value) and I obtained this:

[image: Trends normalized]

Could this be a good approach? In general which approach should I use if i want to compare different curves which have a really big difference in absolute values?

**EDIT** : In the end i normalized my data using a `zscore` normalization for each single line. So basically I computed the mean and standard deviation for each state and then I normalized the single state with its mean and std.
This is the resulting plot:

[image: normalized]

Is this a good approach? Can I now compare the different trends and conclude that there's an overall decrease in the period between 10 and 15 weeks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be better to use a **standard scaler** that removes the mean and divides by the standard deviation. See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) for more info and an implementation using `sklearn`.

**Why?**

At least you should be aware that dividing by the maximum could hide smaller effects. In the case you have an outlier that has a very high value, you would loose the small changes in the corresponding curve. Moreover, you might not compare the same changes between all the curves.

**Edit**

On the question when to use *standard scaler* vs *minmax scaler*, I think a good start is the [sklearn preprocessing page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing) that deeply explains both. Then in [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/43972/when-should-i-use-standardscaler-and-when-minmaxscaler), @Sammy pointed **"Python Machine Learning"** book by Raschka. The author provides some guidance on page 111 when to normalize (min-max scale) and when to standardize data that I requote here:

> Although normalization via min-max scaling is a commonly used technique that is useful when we need values in a bounded interval, standardization can be more practical for many machine learning algorithms. The reason is that many linear models, such as the logistic regression and SVM, [...] initialize the weights to 0 or small random values close to 0. Using standardization, we center the feature columns at mean 0 with standard deviation 1 so that the feature columns take the form of a normal distribution, which makes it easier to learn the weights. Furthermore, standardization maintains useful information about outliers and makes the algorithm less sensitive to them in contrast to min-max scaling, which scales the data to a limited range of values.

Here are some pictures to go with the **Why?** section above.

[image: Raw data without scaling]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, i tried with a zscore normalization and it seems more reasonable. Do you have any resources about general usage of normalization? I also saw that there's the min-max standardization an so on. Is there any metric to check which one could be better in my case?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include some documentation. I am not aware of metrics to check, I think both scalers could be useful depending on what information you want to extract, what you want to compare. Hope it helps